# Excel Menu disabled after making a copy of workbook

Tags: excel, vba, menu, add-in

***UPDATE***: Problem seems to be related to the user form of the Add-in. My workaround has been to use .SaveAs, close the copied workbook, unload the form then re-open the copied workbook. Any thought on what I'm doing wrong?

I have a VBA Add-in that has a simple routine that opens a workbook, uses `.SaveAs` to create a copy then ends.

The copied workbook remains open and seems okay but all of the Excel Menus are disabled.  If I switch to another workbook and back, the menus seem to be reset/enabled.

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this issue?

Here is my menu code:

```
Public Function fxCreateMenu() As Integer

Dim cbControl As CommandBarControl, bControlExists As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
With Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
    .Visible = True
'\Check if Menu is already loaded
    For Each cbControl In .Controls
        If cbControl.Caption = gsMenuName Then
            bControlExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
        'Debug.Print cbControl.Caption
    Next cbControl
'\Check if Menu is NOT already loaded...
        If Not bControlExists Then
            With .Controls
                    With .Add(msoControlPopup)
                            .Caption = gsMenuName
                            With .Controls
                                    With .Add(msoControlButton)
                                        .Caption = "&GIA"
                                        .OnAction = "AE_ShowGIA"
                                    End With

                            End With
                    End With
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Here is my code to copy the workbook

```
Public Function fxCreateTEMPLATE() As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_CreateTEMPLATE

Dim fileSaveName As Variant
Dim wbTemp As Workbook
Dim strPW As String

'\copy system template

'\open template
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\GIATemplate.xlsm", Password:=gstrPW, ReadOnly:=True  '"\GerrityRRTmp.xlsm", Password:=strPW
Set wbTemp = ActiveWorkbook

'\prompt user to save template
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="My GIA", FileFilter:="Excel XLSM File (*.XLSM), *.XLSM", FilterIndex:="52", Title:="Save As")

If fileSaveName <> False Then
    MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
    wbTemp.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, Password:=""
    fxCreateTEMPLATE = -1
Else
    '\Save As Cancelled
    fxCreateTEMPLATE = 0
    wbTemp.Close
    GoTo Exit_CreateTEMPLATE
End If

Exit_CreateTEMPLATE:
Set wbTemp = Nothing
DoEvents
fxCreateTEMPLATE = -1
Exit Function

Err_CreateTEMPLATE:
Select Case Err
    Case 0
        Resume Next

    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error # " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error copying template."
        Resume Next
        fxCreateTEMPLATE = 0            
        GoTo Exit_CreateTEMPLATE


End Select

End Function
```